# How to deal with open array of TControls

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have this code which does not compile:

```
function IsControlOneOf(AControl: TControl; AControls: array of TControl): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  // if AControls <> nil then // does not compile!
  if Length(AControls) <> 0 then // this compiles
    Result := AControl in AControls; // does not compile!
end;
```

I am probably mistaking dynamic array with open array.
How can I test that `"AControl in AControls"`? 
Should I iterate Low(AControls) to High(AControls) and test for match, or what?

Also, Is there a way to set a default value for the open array?

```
AControls: array of TControl = []
```

Does not compile either.

Comment: Better use `TList` for that collection. You'd implement your `IsControlOneOf` function with a single line like `Result := AControls.IndexOf(AControl) <> -1;`. Except that you'd get advantage of simple operations like inserting, deleting etc.

Comment: @TLama, I thought about it. but the TList needs to be instantiated and constructed every time I pass it to the function, which is an overkill I think...

Comment: @TLama that means you cannot use, for instance, open array constructors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The in operator is used with sets. You cannot use it to test whether an element is present in an open array parameter. In fact you can never use in to test if an element is a member of any type of array. You will need to iterate over the array and check each element.

It is expected that you cannot compare an open array parameter with nil. Remember that open arrays are not the same as dynamic arrays, no matter how similar their syntax appears.

Finally, I suggest that you do not pass open array parameters by value. That results in a copy of the array being made which is of course expensive for large arrays, not to mention needless. Declare the open array parameter as const.

---

In your question edit you ask about default parameters. You cannot specify default values for open array parameters. So in order to achieve the flexibility you need you will have to use overloaded procedures instead.

Comment: "do not pass open array parameters by value": Should I also pass AControl: TControl as const?

Comment: That's less important. You can do so. If you use const always then it can get a little verbose. Up to you.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle this is with an enumeration:

```
function IsControlOneOf(AControl: TControl; const AControls: array of TControl): Boolean;
var
  lControl: TControl;
begin
  for lControl in AControls do
    if lControl = AControl then
      exit(true);
  result := False;
end;
```

Unfortunately, this is tagged Delphi 7, so you don't have a few of those language features.  So you'll have to do it the old-fashioned way:

```
function IsControlOneOf(AControl: TControl; const AControls: array of TControl): Boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(AControls) do
    if AControl = AControls[i] then
    begin
      result := true;
      exit;
    end;
  result := False;
end;
```

Comment: Off topic. Do you really use exit and result in the same procedure?

Comment: @David, Delphi 7 didn't know it yet.

Comment: @TLama You misunderstand. I was unclear. I'm surprised to see exit(true) and result := ... in the same procedure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yeah.  `Exit()` is for early exits.  If we're at the bottom of the procedure already...

Comment: To me, the new exit just makes a bad thing even worse. Having failed to include a return statement, no amount of fluff with exit can make things better. Mixing the two idioms in one function makes it harder for the reader to tell where the result is set.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What do you mean?  The new Exit *is* a return statement.  And it only becomes confusing if you're writing functions that are too long anyway, and then the problem is that *you're writing functions that are too long*.

Comment: No, it is not a return statement. It is a function call. I find extreme cognitive dissonance in the idiom mixing in this trivial linear search. That's not down to function length. The Delphi designers got it wrong by not having C style return but it is surely too late to change now. Adding this fake return-like thing to exit just makes it worse.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's not a function call.  Have a look at the generated ASM sometime.  It's a return statement.  I really don't understand why `Exit()` is so confusing to you.

Comment: I am not remotely confused about `Exit()`. I know precisely what it does. I just do not like the design. Returning values from functions is a foundational part of the language. And in my view the Emba designers screwed up twice. And `Exit()` is indeed a function call. Look in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Exit). A language is not defined by the implementation details of the compiler generated code. `Exit` is categorically different from a return statement.

Comment: Well I'm not defending it, but it's definitely more idiomatic (common) to see a result assignment followed by a parameterless Exit than it is to see Exit(Newvalue).     People who are familiar with C/C++ probably cringe when they see that, but people who have only ever used Pascal probably wonder "why would David's shorts get in a knot over that?".   I see both sides there.

Comment: I suppose my main point here is that if you are going to embrace Exit() then it would be best to be all in. If it really was a return statement as you assert, you'd want to use it all the time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's an *early* return statement.  I'm using it here for what it's supposed to be used for.  And the documentation doesn't say anywhere that `Exit()` is a function call. If it was, it would call a function!

Comment: Oh come on. It's right there. It's an intrinsic function. Always has been. Declared as so: procedure Exit;  The documentation could not be clearer. The use of the function call operator () is something of a give away.